# Delphi - How to get Directory with OpenDialog using iPhone as a picture source

Tags: delphi, topendialog

I have a Delphi app (D2010) which lets the user select a JPG file via an OpenDialog. When I select the file from a normal Windows directory, my TOpenDialog.Filename contains the FULL PATH to the file, and my code works.  The issue I am running into is that the user will often be copying the file phone a cell phone.  When the user plugs in the phone, runs my code, the TOpenDialog Shows the files on the cell phone, the user picks the proper jpg file, but the TOenDialog.Filename does NOT contain the path to the file (only the name of the file), so my program cannot find the file.

For both CAMERAS and CELL PHONES, the picture directory is the DCIM directory. For whatever reason, Windows 7 and probably all others, does NOT provide a drive letter to this directory. As such TOpenDialog only returns the file name, not the full path name. This means I cannot copy the file since I don't have a full path name.

So in short, my question is:  How do I use TOpenDialog to get the full path name, when the path is a storage area on a cell phone (in my case, iPhone 5). XE5 has a routine called GetCameraPath, but D2010 does not.

Comment: A little more information:  For both CAMERAS and CELL PHONES, the picture directory is the DCIM directory.  For whatever reason, Windows 7 and probably all others,  does NOT provide a drive letter to this directory.  As such TOpenDialog only returns the file name, not the full path name.  This means I cannot copy the file since I don't have a full path name.  How do I get this name? XE5 has a routine called GetCameraPath, but D2010 does not.

Comment: This additional info belongs in the question itself, not in a comment.

Comment: Remy, Yes it does, but the 'Edit' link is not enabled.  I can share and close, but not edit.  This was the only way I could add the information.

Comment: You can always edit your own question

Comment: On Windows, `TPath.GetCameraPath()` is just a wrapper for [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) requesting the `CSIDL_MYPICTURES` folder ID.