# Reliably accessing virtual drives

Tags: delphi

I have a copy of delphi 5 and been playing with it for a few weeks. Now I would like to make something useful and I thought of a back up for the pictures in my Android phone.

I used an `OpenDialog`, a Button and and Edit. I plugged in the phone and Windows Explorer  displayed 
`motog\internal storage\DCIM\Pictures\IMG_001.jpg`

When I executed the `Open dialog` I navigated to the picture and passed the Filename to the Edit. I then copied that and added it to a test file for later.

`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\YTR4583B\IMG_001[1].jpg`

I rebooted the PC and disconnected the phone. I restarted and ran the program again and got the same path as above.

I shut down the PC and shut down the phone. I restarted both and ran the program again but 
this time I got a slightly different path to the picture.

`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\LFE209GR\IMG_001[1].jpg`

So, I am thinking that the `\YTR4583B\` and `\LFE209GRZ\` are virtual drives, if that's what they are and appear to be assigned at PC start up.

This makes it difficult for a back up program as I would have to manually find the path each time rather than storing the path if it was a normal `C:\` or `D:\` drive.

How can I store the path to the folder on the phone so that it is found each time without having a human to navigate to it?

Comment: In order to preview the picture from your phone, windows makes a temporary copy of the picture in the Temporary Internet Files folder and displays the picture from this copy. The same thing happens when you browse the internet for pictures. They are stored temporarily on your computer in that folder and then displayed in your browser. The 'YTR4583B' folder and the other one is just a random sequence of characters that prevent file name collisions.

Comment: They're not virtual drives. They're temporary folders in the browser cache, as indicated by *Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5* in the path to them.

Comment: OK, thank you, so is it possible to rely on where the files will be every time? How can I store the path to the folder on the phone so that it is found each time without having a human to navigate to it?

Comment: You are navigating a local cache, not the phone directly. The paths inside of the cache are random. If you really want something reliable, you will have to navigate the phone's media storage directly, not a local cache. The USB driver for your phone should be providing a mapped drive letter for the phone's storage media when it is plugged in, assuming your phone itself is configured to provide remote access to its storage media.

Comment: You should study the PC software for your phone closer. Typically, it does not provide a drive or filesystem. Just a same as Control Panel or Network Neighbourhood, it is *shell namespace*. You cannot reach a shell namespace object by filesystem path.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442747