# How to use TOpenDialog to get the full path name from external device (android tablet, iphone)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, topendialog

I have come across the same issue described in the following link, however I'm using Delphi XE2 instead:

[Delphi - How to get Directory with OpenDialog using iPhone as a picture source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442747/)

If anyone could offer any help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess what you are actually describing is part of the shell namespace that is not in the filesystem. In other words, you don't have a file name. You need to learn about shell namespace, PIDLs etc. And you'll need to write code that can operate on shell items rather than files. Quite a learning curve, but I guess that's what is needed. Finally, please don't ever link to sites that scrape SO content! That takes the biscuit. I fixed your link.

Comment: When you get on top of the shell API and shell items, you'll have to switch to `TFileOpenDialog`. This is what gives you access to shell items. Can't do it from `TFileDialog`. If XE2 does not have `TFileOpenDialog` then you will have to wrap `IFileOpenDialog` yourself.

Comment: XE2 does have `TFileOpenDialog`.